# exporting data from excel to display on userform

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I have a userform where I want to display data from a spreadsheet. The spread sheet is an input interface and the calculations will be displayed on my useform. My problem is to fetch the data. I have tried the code below, but what hapeens is that te correct data only appears if the user clicks on the label from the form. I need it to automatically load when i load the form. Where am I going wrong?

```
Private Sub Label3_Click()

Label3.Caption = Sheets("mysource").Range("o3")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Label3.Caption = Sheets("mysource").Range("O3").Value

End Sub
```

Comment: Doesnt work. My problem is the "on click" command. I mean, when the form is loaded, it will show the data correctly IF i click on the label itself. Thats not what i want. I need it to open already showing the correct information.

Comment: Edited my answer. You should add that line in your `UserForm` Initialize event. Modify the name with your `UserForm` Name.

Comment: Thanks!! That's exactly it.